# My column from csv file consists following values and some NaN values I want to extract information from it and store it in new column

Tags: python

`{'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}`

I want to extract information from the above key-value pair, there are few data like this and I want to extract keys from this where value is `True` and store it in new column using python.

Comment: What do you mean by "new column"? Can you please be more specific about your desired output?

Comment: `[key for key, value in dict_.items() if value]` will get you a list of all the keys in the dictionary associated with a true value. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have  data like this {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False} in column named attributes.BusinessParking. I want to extract the keys where the value is True like in this case 'lot'. There are few other values like NaN, None. I want to extract the value 'lot' and store it in new column named "Business Parking"

Answer (score 1):

```py
data = {'garage': False, 'street': False, 'validated': False, 'lot': True, 'valet': False}

new_column = [key for key, value in data.items() if value is True]

print(new_column)
```

output:

```
['lot']
```

Now you can add the extracted value into your dict like so:

```py
data['Business Parking'] = new_column
```